# Running Java application from C# properly

Tags: java, c#, process

I am trying to execute Java application from my c# code. I use Process class from System.Diagnostics.

I am able to run it and kill, but it seems that java starts subprocess when I am executing application. And when I am trying to kill the Process, I kill the parent java process, the second one, which was started behind the scenes, is still running.

Multiple executions of this logic cause dozens of java.exe processes and memory overflow.

Is there a way to do such thing as proper running Java application from c# code and be able to kill started processes?

I wonder if it is possible at all to resolve this issue if I don't have administrative rights

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would be tempted to use [taskkill](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491009.aspx). It runs from this cmd command:

```
string.Format("cmd /c \"taskkill /f /pid {0}\" /t", this.processId);
```

the `/t` does a tree kill, that ends the child processes.

Comment: User which has to run my application has no admin rights. Not sure if I will be able to execute this command programmatically

Comment: Do either `Process.Close` and `Process.Kill` work for you?

Comment: Process.Close or Process.Kill stop the main java process, not the child one. Child process continue working.

Comment: Do you write the java code and can you make it into a more responsible citizen?

Comment: Nope, this Java application is a third party software. That is the pain

Comment: You could try `taskkill /f java.exe` to kill the whole shebang, but whether this is a good idea depends on your situation. If the java spawns are not child processes, there is no way to identify them